# Unhandle Exception Error in ADO.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Data.dll**

[image: System.StackOverflowException]

Comment: Employees.Add rather than Employee.Add ?

Comment: click on **view details** in exception handler and also post more details

Comment: Post the stack trace..